# Computing a second harmonic resistance out of a wave-like resistance signal

Tags: magnetic-fields, fourier-transform, signal-processing, hall-effect

I want to reproduce the results of a **[paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/318221235)**, in which they measure the Anharmonic Hall Effect (AHE) resistance $R_{AHE}^{2\omega}$. There are [several protocols](https://patents.google.com/patent/EP3355074A1/en) for measuring it experimentally, but I'm performing a simulation. I am using a software package which solves the magnetization dynamics of the system through solving the [LLG equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Landau%E2%80%93Lifshitz%E2%80%93Gilbert_equation)

According to the cited paper: *"The current induced alternating effective field will cause the oscillation of magnetization around its equilibrium state, which will generate a second harmonic AHE resistance $R_{AHE}^{2\omega}$"*

Basically, my approach was the following:

1. Compute the $m_z$ (since $R_{AHE}$ is just proportional to the magnetization along z direction) from the simulation data. Since an AC current( $I=I_{ac}sin(2\pi\nu t)$, with $\nu=0.158$ [GHz] ) current passes through, a wave-like signal is obtained.

[image]

2. Perform a Fourier Transform of the obtained signal

[image]

[image]

3. Observe the obtained peaks at the absolute value of the complex-valued result of the FT.

[image]

I pointed three main peaks, the last one at ~0.158 [GHz], the same frequency of the AC current.  Which peak should be related to the $R_{AHE}^{2\omega}$?